# return random value from list when choosing maximum value and have 2 same maximum values

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
key_list=[(2, 'just', 'sd'), (2, 'great', 'sd'), (1, 'just great', 'sd')]
```

I want to choose maximum value at 0 index of list for every element like here maximum value is 2 but when there are two maximum values for same value in different sets, it randomly return the the one element like `(2, 'just', 'sd')` and `(2, 'great', 'sd')` have maximum value of 2 and return any one of them.

I have written

```
max([i[0] for i in list_keys])
```

to get maximum value but don't know how to choose random value based on this '2'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you could do this:

(1) Randomly choose among the entries that match the maximum value:

```
import random
key_list=[(2, 'just', 'sd'), (2, 'great', 'sd'), (1, 'just great', 'sd')]
m = max(i[0] for i in key_list)
print(random.choice([i for i in key_list if i[0] == m]))
```

(2) Use a special key function that applies a random tie-breaker:

```
print(max(key_list, key=lambda i: i[0] + random.random()))
# or
print(max(key_list, key=lambda i: (i[0], random.random())))
```

Comment: @user3499140 If someone's answer helped you it is good if you upvote and/or accept it. This shows others who search for the same problem that this answer provides a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

key_list = [
    (2, 'just', 'sd'),
    (2, 'great', 'sd'),
    (1, 'just great', 'sd')
]

max_value = max([key[0] for key in key_list])
max_keys = [key for key in key_list if key[0] == max_value]

print(random.choice(max_keys))
```

Comment: OP needs to choose from max values only.

Answer (score 0):

You can fist find the maximum value, then randomly select among the tuples containing this maximum:

```
import random

key_list=[(2, 'just', 'sd'), (2, 'great', 'sd'), (1, 'just great', 'sd')]

maxi = max(t[0] for t in key_list)
out = random.choice([t for t in key_list if t[0]==maxi])

print(out)
# (2, 'just', 'sd')
```